Obtaining information about kernel functions in system log entries
I’m currently investigating some entries in my system logs but haven’t been able to find much information through Google.
I’ve also downloaded the kernel source code and tried searching for the following functions, but I haven’t had any luck finding them:

session_getbno
print_bio
find_deadlocked

Can suggest where I might find more details on them? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You did say, "Any help..."
You could add an entry in your syslog.conf to capture kern.debug messages and show them here.  'bio' is for the block driver, maybe you run NFS without a lockd?

Memory was not allocated for the crash kernel meaning there's no memory dump after the crash. I have now allocated the necessary memory, which should provide better insight if the issue occurs again. Upon reviewing the system log, I identified several errors around the time of the crash, including: print_bio failure (unexpected write bio=address), session_getbno failure and the last entry showing find_deadlocked. The Acronis process (service_process and snapapi) and kswap were involved. I would like to gather more details about these functions to further investigate the issue.

wouldn't it be nice if it were something simple like badblocks.

It's an Azure environment. I am not sure how helpful badblock are in these scenario.
